# Cannot log out. Auth0 based React Native Expo application

Tags: react-native, expo, auth0

I'm trying to wrap my head around authentication with Auth0 in a React Native Expo app, however I don't seem to be able to log out. This means I'm not able to switch login accounts either. I'm able to log in the first time I start the app on a new device. After the initial login, silent auth kicks in, and since I'm not able to sign out, I stay signed in.

On logout, I'm hitting Auth0 logout url:

```js
const logout = async () => {
    try {
        await axios.get(`${domainUrl}/v2/logout?client_id=${clientId}`)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}

....

<Button
    title='Sign out'
    onPress={logout}
/>
```

In my Auth0 logs, Auth0 clearly states that: `User successfully logged out`

I'm using the `AuthSessionNew.useAuthRequest()` to handle the login:

```js
const [request, response, promptAsync] = AuthSessionNew.useAuthRequest(
    {
        clientId,
        responseType: 'id_token',
        scopes: ['app', 'name'],
        extraParams: {
            nonce: 'nonce',
        },
        redirectUri,
    },
    discovery,
)

....

<Button
    disabled={!request}
    title='Sign in'
    onPress={() => promptAsync({ useProxy })}
/>
```

As with the logout, I get a successful login in the Auth0 logs whenever I invoke my login-button: `Successful login`

The `response` starts out as null, until the first login. After login, it persists even if the app gets closed or not. I suppose this is a wanted behavior, as you can see if the user is signed in to the application or not this way. However, I guess it should be cleared out once I make the call to the logout route.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Why am I not able to log out, even though the Auth0 logs says otherwise?

Documentation at https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?http#logout
As this is a mobile app, I don't have a redirect-url after logout.
I've also tried the `federated` and it makes no difference.

The response object looks like this:

```
Object {
  "authentication": null,
  "error": null,
  "errorCode": null,
  "params": Object {
    "exp://192.168.10.187:19000/--/expo-auth-session": "",
    "id_token": "JWT-TOKEN",
    "state": "BQK8UJc9sK",
  },
  "type": "success",
  "url": "exp://192.168.10.187:19000/--/expo-auth-session#id_token=JWT-TOKEN",
}
```

Not sure why it says `authentication: null` and `type: success`

I would really appreciate som fresh eyes looking at this. If anything information is missing, just tell me and I'll add it to the post. Thanks in advance.

Stephan Valois

Answer (score 0):

I am currently in the same situation but I have found a temporary solution.

```
WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync('https://YOUR_DOMAIN/v2/logoutclient_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&returnTo=LOGOUT_URL', 'redirectUrl')
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably late for the answer but if someone need it, I did it in the following way:

```js
{name ? (
        <>
          <Text style={styles.title}>You are logged in, {name}!</Text>
          <Button
            title="Log out"
            onPress={async () => {
              setName(null);
              setToken(null);
              window.location.replace(
                "https://<YOUR_DOMAIN>/v2/logout?client_id=<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>&returnTo=<WHERE TO RETURN>"
              );
            }}
          />
        </>
      )
```

Check that I am using window.location.replace, but also you could use window.location.assign